# SAS Compresse delimiter

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have an alphanumeric type column with custom format $CDCLOANTI. I can't delete the character ':' in the column, I always get empty column

```
data WORK.p;

   set  table1 ;

  colonne = COMPRESS(Prenom,':');

RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

The format used to display a variable has no impact of the values stored in the variable.

The only way that using COMPRESS() to remove the : characters would result in making a new variable that is all blanks would be if the only non blank character in the variable were all :'s.

But if you try to display the modified string with original custom format it might be that values with the :'s removed are mapped to blank strings by the custom format.

Look at both variables without using the custom format to see what values are there.

For example to see all of the values where COMPRESS() changed the value you could run this step after your data step.

```
proc freq data= WORK.p ;
  where colonne ne Prenom;
  tables Prenom*colonne / list missing;
  format _all_ ;
run;
```

If that step does not produce any report then none of the values of Prenom had any :'s to remove.

Answer (score 1):

The `VVALUE()` function will return the formatted value of a data step variable.

I'm guessing the variable is a timestamp value, and the variable format is something like `TIME8.` or a DATETIME format.

Try

`colonne = COMPRESS(VVALUE(Prenom),':');`